# An update in Ubuntu 14.04 made chrome so small it is basically unreadable (4k screen)

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, chromium

I was doing just fine with Chrome on a 4K screen in Ubuntu 14.04 until I ran the system updates.  It must have been something in the last few months.  As a side note, I don't use the resolution in 4K, I use it in 1920x1080 due to another issue.

EDIT: Bookmarks bar, tabs, and setting menu are affected.

So, maybe I can simply downgrade chrome?  The Ubuntu Software Center does not have an option to do this.  I would need to see the previous version(s) so I can have an idea on what version I should try.

Comment: What do you mean by "made chrome small" ? Is the text really small? Is the chrome window with everything in it really small? Can you post a picture?

Answer (score 0):

You can set default page zoom, go to `chrome://settings`, click on `Show advanced settings...` and under **Web content** set `Page zoom` to whatever % fits your screen.

Comment: Thanks, that helps web pages, but the Chrome interface does not zoom.